# CoreImage offset picture with wrap around

Tags: swift, image-processing, swift3, core-image

Is there a filter that let you offset an image by a given distance on X and Y axis and that would wrap around the pixels that go outside of the image extents?

Pretty much like the Offset filter in Photoshop.

Thanks!

Comment: How about [CIAffineTile](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIAffineTile)?

Comment: @jtbandes I'll have a better look at it, but it might be that and a combination of something else.  Might be a way!